# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working on sdk 3.0

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, iphone-sdk-3.0

I was working on an app in SDK 2.x and everything was working fine, but now I have updated my SDK to 3.0 and found:

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

of tableview is not working.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: are you doing anything special/complicated with your table?  is it a subview of anything in particular?  does your table look like it's responding to touches, but your delegate isn't being called, or something else?  are all the other methods of your delegate being called except this one?

Comment: ham... all delegate function i used r working fine except didSelectRowAtIndexPth. 
for example i used cellForRowAtIndexPath,heightForRowAtIndexPath,numberOfRowsInSection
these r working fine.
table is responding touch event like i use moveRowAtIndexPath and its working fine.
and i can't understand what u mean by "is it a subview of anything in particular?"
Thankz For ur response.
Usman

Answer (score 1):

The [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9) says:

"You can control whether rows are selectable when the table view is in editing mode by setting the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of UITableView. In addition, beginning with iPhone OS 3.0, you can control whether cells are selectable when editing mode is not in effect by setting the allowsSelection property."

So if things changed from 2.2.1 to 3.0 perhaps you have allowsSelection set to NO.

Comment: got the prob... i was using custom cell and it is calling its touchdown event..
i don't why it was working on 2.2.1 and not on 3.0.
any how now i find the prob and InshAllah ll solve it.
Thankz for ur response David.
Muhammad Usman Aleem